# Difference between temp tables

Tags: sql-server

What is the difference between the below syntax? Fairly new to SQL and I have research the internet for an answer but not really understanding the differences.

```
If object_id('tempdb..#test1') vs If object_id('#test1')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `#test1` exists, then the first example will return a value **no matter which database you are currently in**.  The syntax qualifies the database name and the temporary table name.

The second example will only return a value if you are in the 'tempdb' database and the temporary table exists.

Other than that, the two statements are functionally the same.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what database you're querying from. If you run those queries on the [tempdb] database they're doing the same thing. If you run it from another database it is the equivalent of...

```
If object_id('tempdb..#test1') vs If object_id('DatabaseName..#test1') aka If object_id('DatabaseName.dbo.#test1')
```

When you don't provide the [Server].[Database].[Schema] information it defaults to the default schema for the server/database of where the query is being run.